# Is there a standalone graphical application for configuring Network Manager?

Tags: software-recommendation, network-manager, gui

I was working through [a kiosk computing question](https://askubuntu.com/a/490826/449) yesterday. Somebody is trying to deploy Ubuntu as a single-application appliance in a way that they can hand the machine to a client and it'll let them configure a network on first-boot but after that it'll boot into Firefox.

The booting into Firefox part is simple but configuring networks is somewhat harder. `nmcli` is an option but what if the people handling these machines doesn't understand it? I'd like a graphical method.

Also there's the problem that there might not be an installed underlying desktop environment. Assume this is an Ubuntu Server installed with X, Network Manager and Firefox but no Unity/Gnome/KDE or their various configuration applications.

[Version 0.9.10 of Network Manager](http://blogs.gnome.org/dcbw/2014/06/20/well-build-a-dream-house-of-net/) —with its lovely curses-based `nmtui` command-line app— didn't make it into 14.04... So that's off the cards. I'd prefer to avoid any command line interaction on this one because I'm frankly not sure if the deploying people have password access to the command line. They might only have an on-screen keyboard.

We need to tick the following boxes:

- So **simple** your grandma could use it.
- **Graphical** so we don't have to force somebody to log in via a TTY
- **Standalone** so it doesn't need a desktop running in the background
- **Dependency-light** so we don't need to *install* half a desktop to run it.

What applications are available and (if they're part of a desktop) how do you install them in the lightest possible way?

The original question isn't mine but I can test answers as I have a kiosk-style machine.

Answer (score 3):

- I've tested this with fresh Ubuntu server 14.04 installation on a VBox. Setup with:

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get upgrade
  sudo reboot
  sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg xinit xterm
  sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends install firefox
  sudo reboot
  sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends install network-manager
  sudo reboot
  ```
- It does not seem that many packages as half desktop with `--no-install-recommends`?!

  `sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends install network-manager-gnome`

  ```
  The following NEW packages will be installed:
    dbus-x11 gconf-service gconf-service-backend gconf2-common gnome-icon-theme
    hicolor-icon-theme humanity-icon-theme libappindicator3-1 libatk-bridge2.0-0
    libatspi2.0-0 libcairo-gobject2 libcolord1 libcroco3 libdbusmenu-glib4
    libdbusmenu-gtk3-4 libgconf-2-4 libgnome-bluetooth11 libgnome-keyring-common
    libgnome-keyring0 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common libindicator3-7
    liblcms2-2 libnm-glib-vpn1 libnm-gtk-common libnm-gtk0 libnotify4 librsvg2-2
    librsvg2-common libsecret-1-0 libsecret-common libwayland-cursor0
    libxkbcommon0 network-manager-gnome policykit-1-gnome
  0 upgraded, 36 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
  Need to get 5,787 kB of archives.
  After this operation, 34.2 MB of additional disk space will be used.
  ```
- If not, I don't think this is the best way. What if we remove non-needed features from `network-manager-gnome` package.

  `--disable-migration` to remove gconf dep
  `--enable-introspection=no` no need for gi lib
  `--with-modem-manager-1=no`, `--without-bluetooth` depending on the case
  `--with-gtkver=2` to build it using gtk2 only as firefox no extra
  `--enable-indicator=no`, indicator is gtk3. didn't work for me, raise errors in building

  1. So on other machine/or Vbox, make the minimum build

     ```
     sudo apt-get install dpkg-dev
     sudo apt-get build-dep network-manager-gnome
     apt-get source network-manager-gnome
     cd network-manager-applet-0.9.8.8/
     ./configure --prefix=/opt/nm/ --disable-more-warnings --disable-migration --enable-introspection=no --with-modem-manager-1=no --with-gtkver=2 --without-bluetooth 
     make
     sudo make install
     cd /opt/nm/
     tar czf ~/Desktop/nm-custom.tgz .
     ```
  2. Extract it on target machine

     ```
     sudo mkdir /opt/nm
     cd /opt/nm
     sudo tar xvf ~/nm-custom.tgz
     ```
  3. Install missing dependencies

     ```
     sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends install libnm-glib-vpn1
     ```
  4. Test

     ```
     sudo /opt/nm/bin/nm-connection-editor
     ```

Comment: I wonder, if we're going to all this effort, why not get the NM 0.9.10 source package for `jessie`, and build it for `trusty`? Should be far more simple, and will get @Oli `nmtui` as well.

Comment: @muru, That will be better, debian one does not use libappindicator (Ubuntu specific).