# Adjust ScreenBlank timeout on Firefox kiosk

Tags: command-line, xorg, firefox, screen, xinit

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 set up as a kiosk that starts Firefox in `/etc/init/x.conf` like this:

```
exec su -c "startx /etc/X11/Xsession /home/kiosk/kiosk.sh --" kiosk
```

(see details here: [How to make ubuntu 14.04 a kiosk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/490820/how-to-make-ubuntu-14-04-a-kiosk))

I want the screen to stay on for 60 minutes before going blank, however I haven't been able to overrule the default 10 minutes limit.

This is what I have tried:

- In `lightdm` screen blank options is set to 60 minutes for the kiosk user
- I have tried to add an `/home/kiosk/.xinitrc` file with `xset` options
- I have tried to add an `XAUTHORITY=/home/kiosk/.Xauthority xset -display :0.0 s off` in my kiosk start script
- I have tried to add `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` with `Option "BlankTime" "60"`

What is the correct way to configure screen blank time when starting x with `startx` from a shell script?

Answer (score 1):

Finally found a solution. The `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` is the right way to do it.

This is the `xorg.conf` that is working:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier  "ServerLayout0"
    Option  "DPMS"      "false"
    Option  "BlankTime" "60"
    Option  "StandbyTime"   "0"
    Option  "SuspendTime"   "0"
    Option  "OffTime"   "0"
EndSection

Section "ServerFlags"
    Option  "BlankTime" "60"
    Option  "StandbyTime"   "0"
    Option  "SuspendTime"   "0"
    Option  "OffTime"   "0"
EndSection
```

It's not nessesary to have Blanktime in ServerFlags AND ServerLayout section, but I havn't had time to test which one is best.