# Streaming video from server using NanoPi

Tags: boot, server, software-recommendation, video, hdmi

I am working on a project where I am required to stream some videos hosted at the server onto a display connected to my NanoPi M1 plus via a HDMI cable. I have very little knowledge about it. Which tools should I use for the same?

My NanoPi is simply connected to an ethernet cable and a display screen. I want the video to be streamed to be in HD or UHD quality. My maximum resolution requirement is 4k streaming. Once my NanoPi boots up, it should start streaming the video that it receives from the server onto the screen.

Comment: This is the solution that I'm thinking about: https://askubuntu.com/questions/499578/vlc-unattended-video-playback-of-sporadic-udp-video-source/499589#499589. It's not specific enough to your question, but if you think it's a good idea I will comment under Oli's answer and ask him to post a more specific answer here.

Comment: Hi ... thank you for your response. Appreciate it! I have got this project running .. and doing some more RnD and tuning on it.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer to your own question when you have finished  fine tuning it. You can also click the check mark beside your own answer to mark it as accepted after you have posted it.