# Set up Kiosk with Mixxx in Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, kiosk, mixxx

I want to set up a Kiosk session that only runs Mixxx in order to decrease vulnerabilities of my data and system at a party I'm hosting. I'm thinking of creating another user (call it DJ), so when I log in into DJ, the only thing available is Mixxx. I know that a guest user is an option but any user still has full control of that session.

I've seen many posts about this in askUbuntu but either they are specifically related to a web-browser kiosk or too advanced for me (the closest one would be [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/490820/how-to-make-ubuntu-14-04-a-kiosk), but it mentions a .desktop file and a shell script without discussing it).

I'm using Xubuntu 14.04.02.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From this question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310671/start-ubuntu-without-a-desktop-environment-but-start-an-x-application), the steps are:

1. Go to `/usr/share/xsessions/` **as root** (you can do this by going into the terminal and type `pkexec nautilus` and navigate to your directory)
2. Create a textfile there called `Mixxx.desktop` or whatever the name is `.desktop`
3. Write in

> ```
> [Desktop Entry]
> Type=Application
> Exec=mixxx
> Name=Mixxx
> Comment=Testing
> ```

4. Restart your computer and enjoy :D

If you need to move windows around, you can use Openbox as a window manager. If you do so, you will be able to log out and move windows around. In order to do so, simply replace `mixxx` with `/usr/bin/openbox-session; mixxx`. I recommend you to do so, because it's much more stable than no Desktop Environment.

And If you use Openbox and amazed by the empty screen, right click brings the menu to basic items in Openbox. Install `obmenu` to customize the menu easily.

Comment: Thanks, but the openbox options seem not to be working. After logging in to Mixxx session, it goes back to log in screen. This doesn't happen without openbox, but, as you say, it's quite unstable without it. BTW, in Xubuntu we use Thunar, not Nautilus.

Comment: @luchonacho So you say that If you use Openbox for Mixxx, it won't work? Try to replace `openbox --replace` with `/usr/bin/openbox-session` (`openbox-session` is used for the file `/usr/share/xsessions/Openbox.desktop`.

Comment: Also worth to see: [Porteus Kiosk](http://porteus-kiosk.org/index.html)