# How do I disable the F11 key?

Tags: firefox, kiosk

I want to make a kiosk using Firefox, and I need the F11 key to be disabled so that the user cannot leave the fullscreen.

On top of this, I want Firefox to startup in fullscreen as well. But the few fullscreen addons out there allow the user to see the tab bar (which is a big no-no with what I'm trying to do).

Yes, I am aware of R-Kiosk's existence, however it blocks downloads and right-clicks, which is what I don't want happening. mKiosk is just a mess.

Comment: [This solution](http://askubuntu.com/a/490826/13247) may be more secure/ideal.

Comment: Nah, all I need is to figure out how to disable the F11 key based on what I'm doing. I'm fine for everything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a more general information for creating an Internet kiosk [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124759/customize-ubuntu-for-a-library-internet-kiosk).